# How to set visibility of a control within an UpdatePanel that uses an UpdateProgress control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an update panel on a page which contains nested Panels. It has a Panel with a small form (like a log-in form) and a button. When the button is clicked, a few conditions are checked, and if passed, the first Panel is hidden and the second Panel with a larger form is displayed.

Because the larger form can take some time to load (it pulls data from other sources), the small form panel contains an UpdateProgress control.

All of this works fine.

Then I added a nested Panel within the login form Panel, placed under the UpdateProgress that will display a meaningful error message, such as if the login code is incorrect. This displays as expected. However, if the user then corrects their information and clicks the button again, the UpdateProgress displays properly, but the error message remains visible, even though I try to set it to Visible = false in code-behind.

This page does not use a master page.

Debugging shows that the Visible property does get set to false, although it still displays in the browser.

ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="custom_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
    <!-- meta and link tags -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- h1 and all that -->
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server">
                            <!-- label and text field -->
                            <asp:Button ID="btnBegin" runat="server" OnClick="btnBegin_Click" />
                             <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pnlUpdate">
                                  <ProgressTemplate>
                                      <p>Loading, please wait... </p>
                                  </ProgressTemplate>
                             </asp:UpdateProgress>
                             <asp:Panel ID="pnlMessage" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltlMessage" runat="server" />
                             </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMainForm" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlConfirmation" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </form>
     <!-- javascript - jquery and bootstrap -->
     </body>
</html>
```

Code Behind (I've tried setting visible to false in the Page_Load, in the pnlUpdate_Load event, and in the btnBegin_Click event - but that error message will not go away.

```
protected void btnBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     pnlMessage.Visible = false;
     Page.Validate();
     if (Page.IsValid)
     {
          // check some conditions. if fails:
          ltlMessage.Text = "Reason for failure";
          pnlMessage.Visible = true; // works
      }
}
```

I have tried removing the Visible="false" from the pnlMessage on the ASPX page and placing it in the code behind in Page_Load but I still can't hide it after the message has already been displayed.

How can I hide the pnlMessage Panel after the btnBegin is clicked the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to this. Apparently there isn't a way to do it in .NET - it has to be done in JavaScript.

Here is the code I used to accomplish this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(endRequest);

    var _postBackElement;

    function initializeRequest(sender, e) {
        if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
            e.set_cancel(true);
        }

        $get('pnlMessage').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function endRequest(sender, e) {
        $get('pnlMessage').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```